# LyX <File> <New from Template> all require special modules, why?

Tags: lyx, templates

My question is: Where are the LyX templates that don't require installation of extra packages, classes or modules?  There isn't one for a novel under *New from Template*.

Months ago I tried LyX without reading the manuals.  I hoped could dive in and learn by experimenting.  Instinctively I clicked on *File*, and *New From Template* thinking I could find something suitable to use for a Novel, based on subject matter.

I found templates titled "apa", "APA6", "JASA",  "ectaart" and others that didn't suggest a design purpose.  Perhaps one of those would work, but I didn't want to open each one to try to piece together to see each one's goal intent.  But, after much head scratching I did anyway.  Every single user template required some sort of extra package, module or class, but thankfully the dialog box let me know that this wasn't an error, just a warning that I couldn't produce output.  I believe I was about to start using a template for a journal entry to the American Geophysical Union, without output.  Yet, I could still use the LyX template for composition.  Thankfully I discovered that in the manual first.

That was before I discovered that first the user needs to set their Class, then load the template they'd like to use.  That's available when you drill down through Documents --> Settings and there select *Class* from the menu, and then can pick Memoir, Koma etc., for a Book, or whatever type of document you'd like to compose.

And so now I'm back to just looking for a Novel Template that's requires just the standard classes, modules and packages that LyX has.  I suppose since I can select Memoir under Document --> Settings that it should be able to render PDF output.

Comment: In your command line, try typing `texdoc apa`. :-)

Comment: Note that if you open a template with a missing document class, at the top of that template you'll find a LyX note with a link to the LyX wiki, describing how to install is. For example, the ACM Siggraph template points you to http://wiki.lyx.org/Examples/AcmSiggraph

Comment: I just made a very minor grammar correction to my original post.  Unfortunately, I believe the answer that had been posted has disappeared, along with a couple of Approval-Ups of the question.  I didn't realize question would roll back to zero with an edit.  Hopefully that's just temporary. -- LyX link will be helpful.  The users will be able to checkout the website of each template to figure out if its something relevant to what they need to use.

Comment: A good recommendation:  After install of LyX, the user might want to check out each template's website, then delete the ones that aren't within their field of writing.  Otherwise, they are likely to have to repeat the process of figuring out which templates do what, unless they jot down notes to themselves explaining each template.

Comment: No answers have been posted to this question, and editing won't cause any comments to disappear either. If any comments have been deleted that is likely because the author didn't deem it necessary to keep the comment around. (Oh, and don't write `< ... >`, the brackets cause that to be interpreted as an HTML tag I think, so that isn't printed. I edited the post again.)

Comment: The reason that every template requires more, is that various LaTeX capabilities are spread out among packages. Here is a new document class that is specific to novels, and pre-loads the stuff that is most essential: https://github.com/RobtAll/novel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is that all templates are in the same templates folder. As far as which templates don't require any more installation, that depends on your TeX distribution. As Torbjørn T. said in the comments, each LyX template gives instructions on how to install the necessary files.

If you happen to use Ubuntu and you would like to automatically install TeX Live and also install the files necessary for all LyX templates and examples, run [this script](https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu) as follows

```
sudo ./install-tl-ubuntu --more-tex
```

(be careful to read the instructions of this script either on the github page or with `./install-tl-ubuntu --help`)

Comment: I actually have a laptop dualbooting Windows 7 with MiKTeX and Ubuntu 12.04 wwith TeX Live.  In both cases, nearly All the templates I've loaded so far (to see what they are about) tell me that I can use it, that message isn't an error message, but that I can't produce output until I install the additional items.  They do have a several subfolders to pick templates from.  You've answered my question.